# How to express abstractions?

Tags: design, object-oriented, abstraction

In a program there is an abstraction from an person to a shape. This abstraction is so that collision detection can be performed. Here is my original class hierarchy:

```cpp
namespace Graphics
{

class Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Shape() = default;

    virtual void Draw() = 0;
    virtual bool CheckCollision(float sample_x, float sample_y) = 0;
protected:
    float origin_x, origin_y;
};
 
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Circle() = default;

    virtual void Draw();
    virtual bool CheckCollision(float sample_x, float sample_y);
};
 
class Square : public Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Square() = default;

    virtual void Draw();
    virtual bool CheckCollision(float sample_x, float sample_y);
};

}

class Person : public Graphics::Circle {
public:
    virtual ~Person() = default;

    int GetAge();
    char* GetName();
};

int main()
{
    Person p;
    p.Draw();

    if (p.CheckCollision(10, 10))
    {
        // person collided!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, is there any way to express such abstractions without using classes? Also is this good design in the first place?

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of ways to express abstractions without classes. But why do you want to, and what actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm curious how to do abstractions in other ways, the class inheritance musn't be the only way to do it? I can see typedef's working similarly in C but its not quite the same?

Comment: Abs. is a broad term; it involves coming up with a description or a representation of something that ignores details deemed or found to be irrelevant, but on the flip side, and *more importantly*, it enables you to be precise about things. You can have different kinds of abstractions, for different purposes. Just coming up with a data structure to represent some concept or some *aspect* of some thing is a form of abstraction (modeling). A collision shape is an example of that. Inheritance (if used w/ LSP in mind) is more about abstracting interactions within software (between components).

Comment: For your particular example, it might make more sense if you have, instead of a "Person", something like a 2D game entity that implements the shape interface, *or* more commonly that implements an interface that lets it return a collision shape on demand. Or you might have the entity and it's collision shape associated in some different way (e.g. by a key or an index - thinking of something like the ECS structure here).

Comment: Another point of confusion; we say that inheritance represents an "is a" relationship, but "is a" is a just another word for classification, and every classification has a criterion by which you decide if something belongs within some group. For interface inheritance/LSP, the criterion is that the abstract behavior is the same (adheres to "contract", unspecified details vary within that). So not everything that in the real world can be described as "is a" (by some criterion devised for *other purposes*) automatically translates to an inheritance relationship in software.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thank you for your input, i agree "is-a" is a broad term up for interpretation. It can model classification but also it's not too far-fetched to model things other than classification, such as the abstract relationship between a clockface and circle. Personally it matches the way i problem solve much more directly than say, procedural programs but i'm left still wondering how exactly they made programs in C, considering the abstraction mechanisms are so primitive (typedef struct).

Comment: So, regarding your question: does that mean you're interested less about abstraction in general, but more in the kinds of abstraction that allow for modularization and substitute/plugable components in along the lines of how interfaces/classes do it? (E.g., how people using C could achieve something like OOP using function pointers? (I'm not well-versed in C, but I think I read somewhere that was one of the approaches used))

Comment: @FilipMilovanović i'm more interested in abstraction in general because its a way we as people solve problems. Take for example building a house, we abstract ontop of physics to solve issues like load bearing. Not about modularization/pluggins, more about solving the problem.

Comment: Hm... if that is taken at face value, it might make the question either too broad (enormous amount of material to cover) or too vague (not sure what aspects of problem solving you're interested in, and to what level of detail). I guess an answer centered around a couple of different ways of modeling the same problem (the one you posted) might be a good start, but I'm not quite sure where to go from there.

Comment: Take a look into Entity Component Systems. It might help formulate a better structure. This way anything can have a bounding box. And you can refine the idea of Person, down to more orthogonal concepts so that the same code can be trivially rearranged to make interesting things.

Answer (score 4):

> is there any way to express such abstractions without using classes?

Sure. Some languages don't even have classes. Some don't so much as provide you a simple way to make objects. That doesn't mean they don't have abstractions.

Many seem to think of a class, particularly it's interface, whenever you say abstraction. But functions are abstractions as well, as are arrays, variables, constants, data structures, pretty much everything that has a name is an abstraction. Even some things that have no name. An abstraction is a model of something that only models some features of that thing, not all.

The true art is finding the right abstraction to solve a problem. One that doesn't leak unnecessary details, or lock you into an unhelpful way of thinking, while providing what's needed to solve the problem. One that enables changes to the problem without being brittle.

Here's a collision detection system that deals with shapes but doesn't care about classes. It's abstraction is a pixel.

[image]

Say you need to model this bunch of circles and detect where they are colliding. Your code would use a `Circle` class that inherits from `Shape`. But you could just have a circle drawing function that draws whatever color you tell it on whatever canvas you hand it. Sounds simple but where's the collision detection?

[image]

Have a canvas dedicated to collision detection and give each circle a unique color. Now, in addition to returning a new updated canvas, also return a set of overwritten colors. Each unique color in that set maps to a circle that collided with this new circle.

One of the really nice things about this solution is adding squares is as easy as figuring out how to draw a square. You practically get it's collision detection code for free.

Done this way there are no classes, no objects, just data structures and functions. But it comes at a cost. This is memory intensive (requires two canvases) and we've switched from the vagaries of floating point numbers to the discreet integers of our pixels.

But that's OK. Abstractions are about what you don't model.

> Also is this good design in the first place?

The `Circle -|> Shape` design is popular in textbooks. It's rare in the world of production code. It works but [it has problems](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18250571). Most of them center around how you decide that Shape is the right abstraction. Most humans are mammals. So `Employee` should inherit from `Mammal` right? No? Gee, why not?

Since this answer is long enough as is, I'll let Eric Lippert [answer that](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/).

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/423389/275536) by candied_orange provides an example of a significantly  different approach to representing collision shapes. Your Person however, can be a multi-faceted abstraction; it could implement more than one interface, one of them being Shape. Or it could rely on containment and provide the ability to *produce* a collision shape on demand when used by the collision system (and even a graphical representation, for that matter - like a sprite - when used by the rendering system). Another component could ignore those aspects completely (like the dialog system), but use other properties of the Person object.

> i'm more interested in abstraction in general because its a way we as people solve problems. Take for example building a house, we abstract ontop of physics to solve issues like load bearing. Not about modularization/pluggins, more about solving the problem.

"Abstraction" is a broad term; it involves coming up with a description or a representation of something that ignores details deemed or found to be irrelevant, but on the flip side, and *more importantly*, it enables you to be precise about things (because it clearly delineates what *is* important). You can have different kinds of abstractions, for different purposes. Abstractions can also be wrong. Well, in a certain sense, you could say that *all* abstractions are wrong, it's just the question of how well they capture the thing/phenomenon they were devised to represent.

### Inheritance, and "is-a"

In programming, we tend to conflate abstraction with inheritance; a classic introductory example uses inheritance to model animal classification.

```java
class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Rottweiler extends Dog {}
class Dalmatian extends Dog {}
```

But let me switch that up to make a point. Suppose the year is 2005, and you were using this same approach to model *planets*. Maybe you're making a game, and your players can land on a planet and explore it, and the Planet interface provides a set of methods that make this possible.

```java
class Planet {}
class Mercury extends Planet {}
class Venus extends Planet {}
class Earth extends Planet {}
//...
class Neptune extends Planet {}
class Pluto extends Planet {}
```

Then in 2006, the International Astronomical Union *redefines* what the term "planet" means, and suddenly, Pluto is no longer a planet. Question: Do you change your inheritance hierarchy?

No!

The formal definition of the term "planet", which excludes Pluto

```
    A planet is a celestial body that:
    - is in orbit around the Sun,
    - has sufficient mass to assume hydrostatic equilibrium (a nearly round shape), and
    - has "cleared the neighborhood" around its orbit.
```

has *nothing* to do with your

```
   A planet is a thing that provides an interface 
   that allows a player ship to land on it, to explore it, 
   to mine it for resources, etc.
```

Their "is-a" has nothing to do with your "is-a". They are concerned with classifying celestial bodies for purposes of catalogization and study, while you are concerned with classifying software components based on their behavior. Sure, you might change the value of a property on Pluto to show a different description, but you wouldn't introduce another base class, just because Pluto is, by someone else's criteria that are unrelated to what you're doing, now considered a [dwarf planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_planet) (which is not a kind of a planet, but a distinct thing).

**Liskov Substitution Principle**

This is the whole point behind the [Square-Rectangle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle%E2%80%93ellipse_problem). You derive the Square class from the Rectangle class, because math tells us that the Square is a kind of Rectangle. However, suppose the contract of Rectangle *explicitly states* that Width and Height change independently, and that you have client code that *relies* on that fact. In terms of [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), part of the *behavioral* guarantees of the base class is that changing Width doesn't impact Height and vice versa. However, all sides of a Square have to be of equal length, so it overrides these properties to satisfy this constraint - breaking LSP in the process and causing surprising bugs in client code.

### Remember to challenge your assumptions!

Again, mathematical "square is a rectangle" is based on "its sides make right angles"; your "is-a" should be based on "it has the same abstract behavior, so it can be plugged in where a base type is expected". One has *nothing* to do with the other. As far as you are concerned, in this particular software component interaction scenario, a square is *not* a rectangle - although it might be *to some other code* in your system! Remember the Interface Segregation Principle? A component may be several things at once (it may play more than one role, being a component that "is-a" more then one thing, where each client sees it differently). Although, if you go overboard with that, you get a tangled mess due to increased complexity which is why this is balanced by other design cosiderations (such as the Single Responsibility Principle).

But also, a thing that most definitely "is-not" some other thing, totally *is* that thing in a different context. A square is not a circle, right? A circle is a "closed curve where all points are equidistant from a particular point (the center). Well, if you're working in so called [taxicab geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), a square (although rotated) fits this definition. This is a circle in taxicab geometry:
[image]

And if you ask a [topologist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NlqYr6-TpA), any closed smooth curve is a circle as far as they are concerned, no matter how wavy and out of shape it is, because they don't care about distances, or even the actual shape, all they care about is how different parts of the thing connect to each other.

**Communication is actually trickier than it appears**

These distinctions might seem abstract<sup>1</sup>, but these sorts of things *will come up* in surprising ways. This is why, in the software industry, we're constantly talking about being good at communicating with your team and the domain experts, and about dedicating enough time to study the domain to truly understand the nature of the problem you're solving. More often then you realize, you and  your teammates, or you and domain people, will use the *same terms*, but mean *different* things (sometimes slightly, sometimes significantly different). This sort of thing, unexamined assumptions, is a big part of how people end up with software that gets made "according to specification", yet isn't at all what the business really needed.

---

<sup>1</sup> BTW, I used the term "abstract" here in the everyday sense of "far removed" or "vague", "imprecise". In contrast, abstraction, in the sense that we are talking about here, is what allows you to be *as precise as possible*.

---

### What is "modeling"?

Let me get back to the animal example. Sure, an inheritance hierarchy is one way to do it, and it makes sense in certain scenarios. A Dalmatian "is-a" Dog, and a dog "is-an" Animal. But again, "is-a" is not enough on it's own. What if you decided to represent these relationships as a tree (in this case, with child-to-parent–directed links)?

```csharp
class Animal {
  public Name;
  public Animal IsKindOf;

  public Animal(string name, Animal isKindOf = null) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.IsKindOf = isKindOf;
  }
}

var animal = new Animal("Animal");
var cat = new Animal("Cat", animal);
var dog = new Animal("Dog", animal);
var rottweiler = new Animal("Rottweiler", dog);
var dalmatian = new Animal("Dalmatian", dog);
```

Is this right? Is this wrong? Depends entirely on what your application is for, what kind of problems it needs to solve.

The same abstraction can be *represented* (modeled) in different ways. The abstraction here—the core, simplified notion that captures some details and ignores others, defined around an "is-a" criterion—is that animals can be placed into groups, and that certain animal groups are subsets of other groups<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>2</sup> This is an abstraction because, in nature, things don't always fit so neatly. Is a [liger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger) a lion or a tiger? Or even with non-hybrid animals, sometimes it is unclear where one species ends and where another begins. Scientists shuffle parts of the biological classification, even above the species level, more often then you'd think. In theory, we can group species by their evolutionary relatedness, in practice, things aren't always [quite as simple](https://www.quantamagazine.org/phyla-and-other-flawed-taxonomic-categories-vex-biologists-20190624/). (On that note, if you're making an application for a taxonomist, they might prefer it for you *not* to hardcode these relationships into the type system. Talk to your domain experts!)

---

One *representation* (model) of that was the inheritance hierarchy; this made use of the type system. Another model was the tree-based model above. But you might care about things such as cache locality, and opt to model these relationships like this:

```
struct Animal {
  public Name;
  public int ParentGroupIdx;
  
  public Animal(string Name, int parentGroupIdx = -1) { ... }
}

var animals = new Array[NUM_ANIMAL_GROUPS];
animals[0] = new Animal("Animal");
animals[1] = new Animal("Cat", parentGroupIdx: 0);
animals[2] = new Animal("Dog", parentGroupIdx: 0);
animals[3] = new Animal("Rottweiler", parentGroupIdx: 2);
animals[4] = new Animal("Dalmatian", parentGroupIdx: 2);
// etc...
```

### Abstractions relating to interactions between components

In software, we're concerned with interactions between different parts of the code; in particular, we want to keep certain things decoupled. The go-to technique is to "introduce an abstraction" between the two, but what does that mean?

[image]

Often, it involves an abstract class or an interface, but that's not the limit of the idea. A lot has been written about those kinds of abstractions, so I'll give you some atypical examples instead.

Here's a simple one. How do you write a generic procedure for sorting things, if you know nothing about what determines the ordering of the elements, or even what type they are? Suppose you don't have a compile-time mechanism like C++ templates available. Hm... Maybe callers can provide that information. Let's see... what do we need, *really*? What is the *essence* of this problem? (In other words, what abstraction could be useful here?). Well, if something could *tell you* if two elements are equal, or if one should come before the other in the ordered sequence, then you could perform the sort. Let's call the thing that can provide this information a "comparer". So, all clients need to do is to call sort and provide this "comparer". OK... How do we *represent* this? We need it to return one of three values (<, ==, >). Let's keep things simple and represent these by integers (<0, 0, >0).

And voila, you have an abstraction that captures how the two components (the sort procedure and the calling client code) should interact, and otherwise lets them evolve independently. You must have seen such a function before; [here it is in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__):

```csharp
List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T> comparer);

// use:
people.Sort((personA, personB) => personA.BirthDate - personB.BirthDate);
```

Note that *any* function that adheres to this idea will work. In a sense, that function signature + the semantics associated with this whole idea, is like an interface, but for functions.

Another example of a decoupling abstraction is when you have some kind of a language; but again, it can be simpler than you think. E.g., format strings are essentially a mini language that allows you to be declarative about how you want your string to be formatted, and the the details of the actual procedure that implements that can independently change behind that abstraction. Here it is in C#; the C# team can change the implementation of this in the standard library, and you wouldn't even notice.

```csharp
Console.WriteLine("The property '{0}' is set to: {1:f2}", propName, value);

// Output: The property 'length' is set to: 12.34
```

On a larger scale: The HTML + CSS combo is an abstraction that lets the browser render interactive UI elements without ever knowing what your web page / web application is even about, and also lets you design a UI without having to know how to render text and buttons and images and divs/borders/shadows/whatnot yourself, or how to implement their default behaviors.

Here are some examples on a larger scale still. Your application ultimately communicates with a relational database using an abstraction called the SQL language. A database is an application in its own right, that manages relational data, and both you and database vendors can change how each application works internally. Two web services communicate through an abstraction defined by the combination of web protocols and an API. Or they might communicate through a shared database, the abstraction being the agreed upon schema.

On the other end of the spectrum: If you use a compiled language, you rely on a bunch of abstractions without ever thinking about it. The whole notion of a function, and of a function call with all the associated semantics (parameters that go on the call stack, and local variables, the idea that there's a return value and that it returns to the call site) - that's all an abstraction that you are transparently able to use and rely on. But most of these high-level notions don't really exist as such in the machine language that your code compiles to! The compiler has to *generate code* that essentialy simulates that high-level behavior for you. (This is why sometimes you have to worry about different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)).

Anyway, I have to stop somewhere, and this might be a good place. Hopefully I managed to provide some food for thought.

Comment: Thank you, i agree with your points. Another perspective on this is that we must create "things" in our code, for example, for my game there must be a "thing" called a Person. There is no way around this, so taking that into account we must create the best "things" we can, which is by objects and furthermore by its abstractions too

Comment: @RichardBamford -yes, you have to create some kind of representation for a thing of interest, but it doesn't always have to be a full blown object. E.g., modern games that use the ECS architecture model all entities (cameras, monsters, people, the player, ...) as a combination of focused "components" (individual data structures that store things like translation, rotation, collision shape, ...), while behaviors are modeled by "systems" that can query for a entities with a certain combination of components and apply operations on them. The entities themselves are represented by *just an index*.

Comment: Yes this is true, but where do we draw the line when creating an object? do we stop when its just a record, or do we keep refining it until its a class.etc? I think that an ECS is just a workaround for not doing HAS-A properly. The relation between and entity and component is the as between an object and it composition.

Comment: @RichardBamford "I think that an ECS is just a workaround for not doing HAS-A properly" - I don't think that's right; I think it's a design technique that's a workaround for the fact that modern OO languages take away your control over where and how object's instance state is stored in memory - and in the game dev world, that's not ideal. As for records vs classes; there's a certain design tradeoff there - it's described informally [here](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2019/06/16/ObjectsAndDataStructures.html) (the interesting bit is in the second half of the article).

Answer (score 2):

Much cleaner idea: *"Dear 'Person,' will you please tell me what is your 'Shape'?"* ("Bounding box?")

Because – in all of my many years on Planet Earth, I have never encountered a "person" who actually ***is*** a "shape!"  But all of them could tell me: *"How tall are you?"*

Comment: 'I have never encountered a encountered a "person" who actually is a "shape!"' - on the other hand, mathematically speaking, every person *is* a shape, a 3D-shape that we abstractly refer to as a "humanoid". That's was my point about "is a" not being enough without an accompanying criterion (it bundles several different notions together). And it depends on context; imagine a drawing application that lets you stamp out interactive shapes: a rectangle, a circle, a star, an airplane, a cat, a person - in that context, it could totally make sense.

Comment: In a video game, such a thing could be expected quite reasonably. I’d expect a “Person” object to have at least a reference to data needed to draw it on the screen, to find out if the person can sneak past an opponent in the night, or whether a person can get through a narrow tunnel.

Answer (score -1):

You will likely define something called “interface” or “protocol” depending on your language. An interface describes things that *any* object might or might not support. And instead of saying “I have an instance of class C” you say “I have an instance supporting the interface I”. This doesn’t give you any information about what the class of the object is.